# Unable to build electron 1.6.2 on OSX

Tags: macos, build, electron

I build the electron app with following scripts:

```
script/bootstrap.py -v --target_arch x64

script/create-dist.py
```

The first one ends successfully, but the second one throws this error (from TeamCity log):

*...skipped log entries*

**[02:56:38][Step 2/2]**

`[1315/1328] SOLINK "Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework", POSTBUILDS`

**[02:56:38][Step 2/2]**

`FAILED: ../../vendor/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++ -shared -ObjC -stdlib=libc++ -Wl,-dead_strip -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -arch x86_64 -L. -install_name @rpath/Electron\ Framework.framework/Electron\ Framework -Wl,-rpath,@loader_path/Libraries -F/Users/teamcity/buildAgent/work/e4f0eac9e33806e2/external_binaries -stdlib=libc++ -o "Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework" @Electron_Framework.framework.rsp`

**[02:56:38][Step 2/2]**

`ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/teamcity/buildAgent/work/e4f0eac9e33806e2/vendor/brightray/vendor/download/libchromiumcontent/static_library/libwebkit.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/teamcity/buildAgent/work/e4f0eac9e33806e2/vendor/brightray/vendor/download/libchromiumcontent/static_library/libwebkit.a`

**[02:56:38][Step 2/2]** 

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "blink::WebCryptoKeyAlgorithm::createRsaHashed(blink::WebCryptoAlgorithmId,
    unsigned int, unsigned char const*, unsigned int, blink::WebCryptoAlgorithmId)",
    referenced from:
        webcrypto::(anonymous namespace)::CreateRsaHashedKeyAlgorithm( 
        blink::WebCryptoAlgorithmId, blink::WebCryptoAlgorithmId, evp_pkey_st*,
        blink::WebCryptoKeyAlgorithm*) in libcomponents.a(rsa.o)
    "blink::WebCryptoAlgorithm::rsaHashedImportParams() const", referenced from:
        webcrypto::RsaHashedAlgorithm::ImportKeyPkcs8(webcrypto::CryptoData const&,
        blink::WebCryptoAlgorithm const&, bool, int, blink::WebCryptoKey*) const 
        in libcomponents.a(rsa.o)`

*skipped log entries...*

It looks like the library and build machine are not compatible, but both of them are x64 platforms. What else can be wrong? I put here only part of the log, because it's really very long (thousands of lines). I used to use the same steps for building 1.2.3, 1.2.8 and 1.4.3 versions and there was no problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the ur valid architectures in xcode..